# How to add props to a selector inside a selector in Ngrx

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

```
getSpecialServices = createSelector(
getCustomers,
(customers, props: { type: string }) => ();
```

Taken the above for example i want to actually be able to pass different props to the getCustomers selector also.
I need certain customers based on another props variable.
Is that doable? 
How else can it be done to achieve the same?

Comment: I’d like to know this as well. Good question!

Answer (score 1):

Props are passed to all "child selectors", in your example the `getCustomers` selectors will receive the `props` of `getSpecialServices`.

Comment: Hey.. wait? Seriously? So without actually passing them on? I’m going to have to try that? Will typing of the ‘child’ selector aalo bubble up to the parent?